# Latency of messages running through AKKA Streams keeps worsening

Tags: performance, playframework, akka, akka-stream

**The Problem**

The latency of messages running through our AKKA-streams graph keeps growing with every new message until reaching absurd durations.

The first messages might take 21912 millis to process, the third 41682 millis, the fourth 56987, until we reach (after a thousand messages or so) 3994417 millis.

**The Background**

We are running AKKA Streams 2.4.9 with Play 2.4.6.

Our graph is simple and linear:

SQS Source ~> DB Stage 1 ~> DB Stage 2 ~> Computational Stage 1 ~> Computational Stage 2 ~>... ~> Computational Stage n ~> DB Stage ~> SQS Stage

Clearly the graph has a three parts: the first and the third parts are I/O-intensive and the second part is CPU intensive. Following the [advice](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.9/scala/stream/stream-io.html#streaming-file-io]) to

> ...isolates the blocking file IO operations from the rest of the
>   ActorSystem allowing each dispatcher to be utilised in the most
>   efficient way

we use the ‘custom-blocking-io-dispatcher’ for the stages in the first and third parts, and the default dispatcher for the computational stages.

The SQS-source is implemented like the example in http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.9/scala/stream/stream-customize.html#graphstage-scala

```
class SqsSource(pullElements : () => List[(Result, Message)]) extends GraphStage[SourceShape[(Result, Message)]] with LazyLogging {
  val out: Outlet[(OCRResult, Message)] = Outlet("SqsSourceForProcessing")
  override val shape: SourceShape[(Result, Message)] = SourceShape(out)
  private var counter = 0

  override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): GraphStageLogic = new GraphStageLogic(shape) {
    val mutableInnerQueue: mutable.Queue[(OCRResult, Message)] = mutable.Queue()
    def fetchElement() = {

      if (mutableInnerQueue.isEmpty)
        mutableInnerQueue ++= pullElements()

      mutableInnerQueue.dequeue()
    }

    setHandler(out, new OutHandler {
      override def onPull(): Unit = {
        push(out, fetchElement())
      }
    })
  }
}
```

where 'pullElements' is a tail-recursive function that asks AWS-SQS for messages and if no messages were retrieved calls itself.

It's worth noting that most of the processing stages take negligible amount of time (bellow 15 millis), one of them takes 13067 millis, the DB-stages take no more than 20 millis, and the last SQS-stage takes circa 1400 millis. The overall duration seems to be inflated by the time it takes the message to move from one stage to another.

Comment: How are you measuring the latency?

Comment: We use System.currentTimeMillis() to add the 'start time' to each message at an early stage and then we use it again to calculate the total duration at the end. In addition we measure in a similar way the execution duration of the code thats executed in each stage.

Comment: Then i propose that your "bug" might be that you're not taking buffering into consideration.

Comment: But the question remains: why does my system's buffering cause such a long latency? What explains the phenomenon of the growing latency (instead of it just staying constant)?